# Cannot invoke mult(float) on the primitive type float

Tags: parameter-passing, processing

I'm working on a simple gravity program in Processing. My program takes particles and attracts them to each other based on the formula for gravity. Unfortunately, once I try to multiply the force to the direction with `PVector.mult()`, I get the error in the title:

> Cannot invoke mult(float) on the primitive type float.

Here is my code for the method. G is defined elsewhere.

```java
public float distance(Particle other) {
    return location.sub(other.location).mag();
}

public PVector direction(Particle other) {
    return location.sub(other.location).normalize();
}

public void gravity(Particle other) {
    float grav = (G*((mass * other.mass)/pow(distance(other), 2)));
    if(distance(other) != 0) {
    acceleration.add(distance(other).mult(grav));
}
```

Why am I not able to pass a float where a float is due?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that we can copy-paste to see the error ourselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take this line apart and split it into multiple steps:

```
acceleration.add(distance(other).mult(grav));
```

Here's my attempt to split it into multiple lines:

```
float grav = 42;
float distanceFromOther = distance(other);
float multipliedValue = distanceFromOther.mult(grav);
acceleration.add(multipliedValue);
```

Hopefully this makes it more obvious what's going on: you're trying to call `mult()` on a `float` value, which won't work. You need to call `mult` on a `PVector` or another class that contains a `mult()` function.

Comment: What a simple mistake. I mixed up distance and direction, likely because they both start with d. How embarrassing ~~